# How do I implement a minimum priority queue

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I already know priority queues are implemented by default as max_priority queues in C++. 
But how to make a min priority queue, rather than storing negetive of each number.
Please help , I am unable to find the syntax , and if able to find any syntax unable to use it and understand it :(.

Comment: Reverse the comparator logic? I.e use `std::greater<>` rather than `std::less<>` as the comparator.

Comment: Any code will help :)

Comment: `std::priority_queue<YourType, std::vector<YourType>, std::greater<YourType>>`, and of course you can use a different sequence container if you want, such as `std::deque<YourType>` See the docs on [`std::priority_queue<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) for more info.

Comment: People won't code up things for you here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/

Use the constructor that allows you to pass your own compare object.

> template < class T, class Container = vector,
>              class Compare = less > class priority_queue
>
> Compare: Comparison class: A class such that the expression comp(a,b), where comp is an object of this class and a and b are elements of the container, returns true if a is to be placed earlier than b in a strict weak ordering operation. This can either be a class implementing a function call operator or a pointer to a function. This defaults to less, which returns the same as applying the less-than operator (a